# Where are users coming from?

Tags: discussion, users

This site depends on its users and therefore should understand current and future user needs, should meet user requirements and strive to exceed user expectations.

In order to understand user needs, user requirements and user expectations, we need to know who the users are. Hence, we may be interested to know where they come from.

Answer (score 6):

This graph shows the number of views per month of all the pages on german.stackexchange.com. A page view is an instance of a page being loaded by browser.

[image]

[(Link)](https://www.quantcast.com/german.stackexchange.com?country=US)

Top countries during the last month (January 18, 2015 – February 16, 2015):

```
Germany        35 %
United States  21 %
United Kingdom  7 %
Austria         5 %
Switzerland     3 %
Rest of World  28 %
```